# set google-static-maps width 1024px and more?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

How to set card width 1024px and more? How to leave names of streets in one language? It is now removed names in two languages(rus. and eng.). And how to fight against increase in a tag in case of scale=2 ?

Comment: purchase a business license, it allows a size up to 2048x2048

Comment: didn't find the cost and methods of connection of the license where it is possible to read about it?

Comment: http://www.google.com.hk/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html

Comment: okey, thanks. and what on another you can tell? Concerning a uvilicheny marker on a maps how to make that the marker wasn't scaled in case of scale change?